# How to unmarshal in Go when dealing with dynamic fields

Tags: go, unmarshalling

I'm learning Go and trying to implement it. My JSON data looks like this:

```
{
    "site1": [
    "site1_router01",
    "site1_router02"
    ],
    "site2": [
    "site2_router01",
    "site2_router02",
    "site2_router03",
    "site2_router04"
    ],
    "site3": [
    "site3_router01",
    "site3_router02"
    ]
}
```

How would I create a struct for this data type?
I tried this:

```
type site map[string][]string
type siterouters struct {
    site
}

func main() {
    var input []byte
    for in := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin); in.Scan(); {
        input = append(input, in.Bytes()...)
        input = append(input, '\n')
    }

    // fmt.Println(string(input))
    data := []siterouters{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &data); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}
```

But when I run the code I get this error:

```
go run test2.go < prod-slr.json
'json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.siterouters
```

The JSON file can have any number of sites, and any number of routers associated to a specific site. Site will always be unique.
Thank you.

Comment: If you are new to go, it would be best to avoid embedding. In this case, you are embedding a type (map) that has no method set, so embedding provides no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've created two unnecessary layers; your code would work if the quoted JSON was inside a `[{"site":{`, but it's not. Get rid of the two outer layers - the struct and the slice - and unmarshal straight into the map:

```
data := map[string][]string{}
if err := json.Unmarshal(input, &data); err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
fmt.Println(data)
```

Working on playground: https://play.golang.org/p/IMrddWu8JAx